# Change body size height

Tags: javascript, html, height, document-body

Is there any way to change the body height. I tried:

```
if(document.body.scrollHeight > document.getElementById('DIVBODY').scrollHeight) {
  document.body.scrollHeight = document.getElementById('DIVBODY').scrollHeight
}
```

But it does not work.
I dynamically change my DIVBODY content and I don't want my  to be bigger than the div DIVBODY.

body and div:

```
<body background="images/grey-lines.png" style="overflow-y:scroll" >

<div id="DIVBODY" style="max-width:1102px; margin: auto; width: expression( Math.min(parseInt(this.offsetWidth), 1102) ); height:100%; text-align:center; align:center;
background-image: url(bg/wood-3.jpg) ; background-color:#af7746; background-attachment:fixed;  background-position: top center ; background-repeat: repeat;  border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; height: auto; min-height: 100%; _height: 100%;">
```

Comment: please show simply document.body.scrollHeight and document.getElementById('DIVBODY').scrollHeight before your "IF" to debug it

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight):

> `scrollHeight` is a read-only property.

You can try [`element.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) and `element.style.height` to accomplish what you want

Comment: @MDN it looks like you can enlarge body height with for example:
`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.height = "40000px" ;`

But you can't reduce it, even if content if <body> is bigger than the content !

Any idea to reduce body height ?

Comment: im with the same doubt than defacto